# Java String Computation : Need Best Optimized solution

Tags: java, arrays, string, algorithm, data-structures

Need your opinion on the best possible solution to manipulate and increment a String.

System has codes similar to "RE", "MA" (system defined) or any user defined,  which will be used by multiple entities. Each entities need to be associated with unique code; For that we need to suffix the system defined code with sequence number.

- RE1
- Random String
- RE2
- RE3
- Random String
- RE4
- MA1
- RE5
- MA2
- etc

For Example consider Bank Accounts. Assume that all accounts to be associated with a code. But Specifically for Checking account and Cash Account code needs to be of format RE* and MA* respectively.

- Checking Account1 --> RE1
- Checking Account2 --> RE2
- Cash Account 1 --> MA1
- Cash Account 2 --> MA2
- Credit Card Account --> Random String
- etc

Now whenever we add a new entity, we need to identify the next sequence to be used based on type. Whats the best way to solve this in Java?

Comment: Maintaining a counter helps ?

Comment: It will not as this counter will have to initialised as system comes live every time. Also as there multiple flows where this code can be generated, it might be bit troublesome to introduce synchronization

Comment: In such cases, I'll get the last item in the the array and get the index ?

Comment: What would be the purpose of an "array"? You have one or more codes like "RE", each for some entity, and a counter indicating the last one actually used. So you have a `Map<String,Integer>` Serialize on shutdown, etc, etc. All very simple.

Comment: Updated my qsn as there is no fixed string. Code can be any string depending upon the entity Type its going to be associated with.

Comment: Then you have an additional mapping java.lang.Class to code String. I don't see the problem - you should have a way of determining the code string from the class right now, either by some definition or create a new (random) string.

Comment: All the associated entities are of the same class type. so i will not be able to maintain the map. Even if I maintain the map, on server startup we need to initialise that map which we are trying to avoid.

Comment: Which program is responsible for creating a "new sequence" (with a new prefix)? Which program is responsible for incrementing the counter? What should happen if this program stops (for whatever reason) and starts again?

Comment: There are only two basic approaches that make sense: either you keep all of your codes in persistent storage (e.g. a database, text file, etc.) or you initialize some shared data structure (List, Map, etc.) at startup and maintain it while you're running.

Comment: Prefixes are fixed either it can be "RE" Or "MA" Or any user defined. Suffixes are applicable only for RE and MA. In case of RE or MA, counter needs to get us the next sequence. On start of program, counter need to initialised to the next value of last used number.

Comment: I think you need to explain a bit about you environment. It is quite difficult to give a decent answer without knowing things like how you are storing the data. For example are you using a database for these Strings? Without a database you will need some other way of re-initializing your counters at startup, either by reading through the previously produced strings, or by serializing the counter for each string to disk before shutting down.
Unless you use a truly unique UUID.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an array for this. Use a map.

```
Map<String, Index> prefixes = new HashMap<>();
prefixes.put("RE", 0 /* or whatever appropriate initial value */);
prefixes.put("MA", 0);
```

Now, whenever you create a new entity, just do this:

```
int nextIndex = prefixes.get("RE") + 1;
String value = "RE" + nextIndex;
prefixes.put("RE", nextIndex);
```

Comment: This needs this map to be initialised on application start up. For that we need to iterate over all codes to determine the next sequence to be used

Comment: Yes, you have to determine the initial value. So, either you iterate once at startup to initialize the map, or you iterate every time to determine the next value of the sequence.